# Is it possible to make a shorter Query without two Subqueries

Tags: mysql

I constructet a Query for my Table which fits my needs. But i assume that this is not the best way to make this Query.
The Table which i have is very simple, it has only two Columns:

```
------------------------------------------
|     _dti_stamp      |      _js_dp      | <- Column Name
|---------------------|------------------|
|   TIMESTAMP-FIELD   |    JSON-FIELD    | <- Array
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-01-01 12:10:15 |[2351442, 0, ...] | <- Record Example
------------------------------------------
| 2019-01-01 12:15:17 |[2351583, 0, ...] | <- Record Example
------------------------------------------
```

My Primary Key is _dti_stamp, because i only want to Lockup Data based on the Timestamp.

I get multiple new Records every Day.

In this JSON-ARRAY are Entrys which are Counters, they're just Integers which increment from time to time, depending on how much Energy was generated by some Photovoltaic-Panels.

What i need is to get the first and the last _dti_stamp for every day i want to check and the corresponding values for them, subtract one from the other and return the Results as two columns _day and _diff.
This gives me the ability to Show how much Energy was generated each Day.

My Query i came up with looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    _max_query._day AS _day,
    (_max_query._data - _min_query._data) AS _diff
FROM
    (SELECT 
        _subquery._day AS _day,
            JSON_EXTRACT(_js_dp, '$[97]') AS _data
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(_dti_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AS _day,
            MIN(_dti_stamp) AS _tmin
    FROM
        TTConnect.CL_2
    WHERE
        _dti_stamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-10'
    GROUP BY _day) AS _subquery, TTConnect.CL_2
    WHERE
        _dti_stamp = _subquery._tmin
    GROUP BY _day) AS _min_query,
    (SELECT 
        _subquery._day AS _day,
            JSON_EXTRACT(_js_dp, '$[97]') AS _data
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(_dti_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AS _day,
            MAX(_dti_stamp) AS _tmax
    FROM
        TTConnect.CL_2
    WHERE
        _dti_stamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-10'
    GROUP BY _day) AS _subquery, TTConnect.CL_2
    WHERE
        _dti_stamp = _subquery._tmax
    GROUP BY _day) AS _max_query
WHERE
    _min_query._day = _max_query._day
GROUP BY _day;
```

The Output i get from this Query looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
|         _day        |      _diff       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-01     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-02     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-03     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-04     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-05     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-06     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-07     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-08     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|      2019-01-09     |    3444023       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
```

(It is a Testdateset, which i generated)
So my Code does what it should (i simplified it a bit, because like you can see, the last day which i wantet to have is not in the Response, but with a simple DATE_ADD() INTERVAL 1 DAY i get where i want).
The Responsetime is also OK i guess, i made my Testset ~308000 Rows long and the time to get the data above was 0.015sec.

I'm by far not a Pro with Databases, but even if it works with this approach it seems there should be at least a more elegant way to reach the goal or is this normal to structure a query this way?
BTW i'm using MySQL 5.7.14.

Comment: What is your question again? Are the results incorrect?

Comment: `It is a Testdateset` Sharing is caring

Comment: @SalmanA The Results are correct, but i'm not sure if this is a good way to solve my Problem.